# Active learning for simulation parameters

Tags: machine-learning, active-learning

Suppose we are training a neural network (or more generally, your favorite nonparametric model) $f: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ to solve a regression problem. For clarity, $k$ is of the order $\sim10$. Each training data point is then of the form $(x_1,\dots,x_k,y),$ and the loss is $L = \sum_i d(f(\mathbf{x}_i),y_i),$ where $d(y,y')$ is some positive-definite measure of the deviation between $y$ and $y'$, and the index $i$ refers to samples.

The training data are extracted a posteriori from (expensive) simulations via postprocessing, with each simulation providing many thousands of data points. Crucially, for a given set of simulation parameters (for instance, initial conditions), the distribution of data in feature space is very difficult to predict. I want to implement an active learning protocol that selects new sets of simulation parameters in order to explore new regions of feature space, so as to obtain a best estimate of $f$ while minimizing the requisite number of simulations.

In other words, I can easily figure out which regions of *feature space* require more exploration, but the correspondence between simulation parameters and these regions is unclear. We could say that each set of parameters $\theta$ corresponds to an unknown data density in feature space $p(\mathbf{x} | \theta)$. What tools are available to perform the task of selecting new simulation parameters? Is there a way, say, to cast it as a Bayesian optimization problem?